# Select group of ids that have values that not all exist in another table

Tags: sql

I have two tables. One with a list of ids and values (one-to-many). And another table with a list of values that are used to match those values in the first table. I want to get all the ids in the first table which do not have all the values in the second table. If an `id` in `ownercars` have all the `code` values associated with it from the `carcodes` table, they should not be returned at all.

ie

```
ownercars
id | code    |
1  | carA    |
1  | carB    |
1  | carC    |
2  | carD    |
3  | carD    |
3  | carE    |
3  | carF    |
4  | carD    |
4  | carE    |

carcodes
|code     |
| carD    |
| carE    |
```

This query should return `id` 1 and 2 as `id` 1 is missing carD and carE and `id` 2 is missing carE.

I have tried join both tables where a code is null.

Although this is still returning `id` 3 in the above example as it sees that carF does not exist in the `carcodes` table and simply returns it. But excludes `id` 4 as all exist in both.

I have also tried through comparing counts between what `carcodes` exist in the `ownercars` table and what each id has, although this works it is not performant.

I have looked into using `ANY` or `ALL` but without success.

```
SELECT oc.id
FROM ownercars as oc
LEFT JOIN carcodes as cc
on oc.code = cc.code
WHERE cc.code IS NULL
```

I want to be able to exclude `id` 3 based on the fact all codes exist in it. What changes to the previous query need to be made to do this?

Comment: Perhaps you meant `WHERE cc.code IS NULL`. The way it is written it returns nothing.

Comment: @Deepstop yep sorry my bad, was just a mistype in converting to a different example from my original query, corrected that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query.

```
SELECT ID FROM carcodes
WHERE ID NOT IN (
    SELECT ID from ownercars 
    WHERE CARCODES in(SELECT cc.code FROM carcodes) 
    group by id having count(*) =2
)
```

Comment: I need the Id from ownercars if I'm understanding this implementation correctly. I've adjusted it to return as such, though it returns all results:
```SELECT id 
FROM ownercars as oc
WHERE oc.Id NOT IN (
    SELECT ocs.Id from ownercars as ocs
    WHERE ocs.code in(SELECT cc.code FROM carcodes as cc) 
 group by ocs.Id  having count(*) =2
)```

Comment: excuse that, that adjustment seems to return exactly what I'm looking for, although with the count concern with performance, I've had a similar implementation before

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT oc.id
FROM ownercars oc LEFT JOIN
     carcodes cc
     ON oc.code = cc.code
GROUP BY oc.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT cc.code) < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM carcodes);
```

If there are no duplicates in `ownercars`, then you can use `COUNT(cc.code)` rather than `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.